# SQLAlchemy (Flask) Migrating DB causes "too many values to unpack" error

Tags: python, flask

I've gone through the other similar threads, but they haven't been too relevant.

The problem came up when I added the password field, shown below:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user'    
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
password=db.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512','md5_crypt'],deprecated=['md5_crypt']))
```

Creating the database goes fine, but when I try to migrate the tables into it, I get the following error:

```
  File "db_migrate.py", line 12, in <module>
  script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in make_update_script_for_model
  File "/home/dale/anaconda3/envs/suggester/lib/python3.5/site-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 90, in catch_known_errors
  return f(*a, **kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-12>", line 2, in make_update_script_for_model
  File "/home/dale/anaconda3/envs/suggester/lib/python3.5/site-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 160, in with_engine
return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/dale/anaconda3/envs/suggester/lib/python3.5/site-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 321, in make_update_script_for_model
engine, oldmodel, model, repository, **opts)
  File "/home/dale/anaconda3/envs/suggester/lib/python3.5/site-packages/migrate/versioning/script/py.py", line 70, in make_update_script_for_model
genmodel.ModelGenerator(diff,engine).genB2AMigration()
  File "/home/dale/anaconda3/envs/suggester/lib/python3.5/site-packages/migrate/versioning/genmodel.py", line 219, in genB2AMigration
 for modelCol, databaseCol, modelDecl, databaseDecl in td.columns_different:
  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

### Any suggestions would be appreciated.

More details:

[PasswordType](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.password) is a [sqlachemy-utils class](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.password). I just copy and pasted it, so I don't think the issue is with the implementation at least.

I'm also using Miguel's db_migrate file, which has worked well up to this point for me:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec(old_model, tmp_module.__dict__)
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

Comment: @user3245721: I also got such error. I solved it running the `./db_migrate.py` command two times. 1st before doing the changes to model. Then I executed it again after changing the models. It simply updated the tables without any problem. Strange but it worked for me. 
Also I used MySQL and Python3.5 while following Miguel's tutorial.